# How to reuse/extend closed java webapp (.ear)?

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish-3, ear

I've got webapp project written in java (.ear).
It is running under glassfish-3 server.
I really have to extend its functonality. but there is no way to change even a line of it.
Is it possible to wrap that webapp or anything else (it has no API, only html for user)?
I know it's very generic, but i cannot provide a code or other useful things.

A similar situation to mine would be (expect my case needs much SECURITY because of sensitive data)...
Let's have a blog application (this would be the java closed webapp), which allows everything You expect from an blog app, BUT one instance handles one user.
You would like to allow new user to create blog (new instances of blog app?). The instances should be isolated each other.. but it's simple to achieve. Different instance different db and so on..

I do not expect solution (because of my generic description) but direction where to go.
I'm java novice, but i can read and reason so.. :)

Answer (score 0):

.ear is just a zipped file, see doc http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAR_(file_format). You can always unzip it and get hold of all files. JSP and config-files can be altered but not the java-classes (unless you decompile them).

This not a complete solution but hopefully a hint in some direction...

Comment: Thanks for that. But i have no idea how could i use that files?
I think my target is to write a new webapp (ideally in django, not changing existing one), which could give possibilty of creating new instances of finished java webapp in subdomain. Yes, it's the way i've just imagine that.